# cannot get device.uuid in android cordova

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, eclipse, cordova

why i cant get device.uuid from my android, i am using cordova. is that because conflict with other js library, but if i delete the other js, some function unable to work.

here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- jQueryMobile -->
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>


        <!-- Owl Carousel -->
        <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

        <!-- DAISY JS -->
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

<script>

function onLoad() {
alert("test");
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

    }


    function onDeviceReady() {
        var macstr = device.uuid;

        alert(macstr);

    }
</script>
 <body onload="onLoad()">
</body>
```

pls help anybody, i am stack here...

tks

Comment: you have corodova.js two times?why? remove the top-one and check.jQuery library need to be placed first.

Comment: oh how i miss that....thank you my brother

Comment: Now it's working or not?

Comment: did you install device plugin?